Is there any way to make Windows always start on a specific audio output?
Sometimes I turn off the computer using the headsets, but I usually use the speakers more.
This would be a quality of life feature.

Yes.  You can use NirSoft's SoundVolumeCommandLine utility.  It's a freeware tool that allows the user to set, amongst many functions, the default playback device.
You'll want to use the /SetDefault command line parameter, as detailed in the tool's documentation.
Once you have created the command you need, simply create a 1-line batch file to call it, and then add that batch file to the Startup group in the Windows Start menu.

just wondering, can you tell me how to do this? I tried everything that is written just doesn't work for me.

I don't have a Windows box available, but I think I published a demo using that tool a while back.  Let me see if I can locate it and I'll give you the exact syntax I used.

I found what I needed to help you.  If you're around right now, we can chat, and I can walk you through it.  If you're not around, I'll post tips I think will help you.

Okay, you're not around, so here's what I recommend trying: use the /SetDefault command line parameter instead.  If the name of the speakers does not contain spaces (it shouldn't), do not use quotes when specifying it after that parameter.  After the name of the speakers, add a space, then specify 1 to indicate multimedia.  You can also specify all to indicate every audio type, but I recommend starting with 1 to get things working.

Here's another tip: You can experiment with the GUI version of SoundVolumeView (available at https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/sound_volume_view.html) before trying to perfect your syntax for the CLI version.  It's easy to play around with the GUI version and you get instant feedback to see if what you are trying to accomplish is working.  Be careful with volume levels... don't overwhelm your ears or speakers/headphones; set the volume to a lower level before experimenting.

A final tip: After you get everything working, you can also use SoundVolumeCommandLine to set the default volume.  This way, your computer will always have the same volume when you boot.  If you want to get fancy, you can even write a batch file to set the boot volume dependent on the time of day.  The sky's the limit.

It was exactly what I needed (I'm not that good at working in this area). Your reputation here is high I guess now I know why
